# Advanced XPath query

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PrivateSchool>

     <Teacher id="teacher1">
         <Name>
           teacher1Name
         </Name>
    </Teacher>

    <Teacher id="teacher2">
        <Name>
            teacher2Name
        </Name>
    </Teacher>

  <Student id="student1">
    <Name>
      student1Name
    </Name>
  </Student>

  <Student id="student2">
    <Name>
      student2Name
    </Name>
  </Student>

    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />
    <Lesson student="student2" teacher="teacher2"  />
    <Lesson student="student3" teacher="teacher3"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher2"  />
    <Lesson student="student3" teacher="teacher3"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />
    <Lesson student="student2" teacher="teacher4"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />

</PrivateSchool>
```

There's also a DTD associated with this XML, but I assume it's not much relevant to my question. Let's assume all needed teachers and students are well defined.

What is the XPath query that returns the teachers' NAMES, that have at least one student that took more than 10 lessons with them?

I was looking at many XPath sites/examples. Nothing seemed advanced enough for this kind of question.

Comment: That sounds like a question you would typically answer from a **database** - not a humunguous XML file...

Comment: I assume that the "linkage" to the teachers' NAMES made you think of a database... If so, let's drop that requirement for the sake of discussion. So, the teacher's IDs are sufficient. How would you implement this now?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and understandable XPath 2.0 expression that produces the wanted teachers names. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a complex join in a single XPath may be possible, but you're banging your head against a brick wall. XQuery or XSLT are much more suited to this kind of thing. Here it is in XQuery:

```
declare variable $doc as doc('data.xml');

declare function local:numLessons($teacher, $student) {
  return count($doc//Lesson[@teacher = $teacher and @student = $student])
};

$doc//Teacher[some $s in //Lesson/@student satisfies local:numLessons(@id, $s) gt 10]/Name
```

Having done that, if you are really determined you can reduce it to XPath 2.0:

```
doc('data.xml')//Teacher[
   for $t in . return 
     some $s in //Lesson/@student satisfies 
       count(//Lesson[@teacher = $t and @student = $s]) gt 10] /Name
```

Not tested.

Comment: Doing this in one XPath is possible? How? I've often wondered how to get around the limitation that `current()` is not available in XPath, I'd *love* to see a way for doing this in a self-contained XPath (1.0, I mean) expression.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think this is posible in XPath 1.0 with **two attributes**. With only one, you can nest predicates in the preceding or following axis for counting equals.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Actually the Xpath expression is not that complex. Both @Alejandro and I make this fact obvious in our answers.

Comment: @alex: Any pure XPath 2.0 solution (such as mine and that of @Alejandro) is also an XQuery solution since XPath is a subset of XQuery. You need to seriously consider the added advantages of using a pure XPath 2.0 solution: 1. It is usable with every XPath 2.0 engine (not only with XQuery). 2. It is usable with every XSLT 2.0 processor. In short, by deciding to use an XPath - only solution you significantly increase the usability and application area of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XPath 2.0 solution:

```
(/PrivateSchool
   /Lesson)
      [index-of(
          /PrivateSchool
            /Lesson
               /concat(@student, '|', @teacher),
          concat(@student, '|', @teacher)
       )[10]
      ]/(for $teacher in @teacher
         return /PrivateSchool
                   /Teacher[@id = $teacher]
                      /Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $limit in 2,
    $t in /*/Teacher,
    $id in $t/@id,
    $s in /*/Student/@id,
    $numLessons in
       count(/*/Lesson[@teacher eq $id
                     and @student eq $s])
 return
    if($numLessons gt $limit)
      then
        (string-join(($t/Name, $s, xs:string($numLessons)), ' '),
          '&#xA;'
         )
      else ()
```

**here I have set `$limit` to 2, so that when this XPath expression is evaluated against the provided XML document**:

```
<PrivateSchool>
    <Teacher id="teacher1">
        <Name>teacher1Name</Name>
    </Teacher>
    <Teacher id="teacher2">
        <Name>teacher2Name</Name>
    </Teacher>
    <Student id="student1">
        <Name>student1Name</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student id="student2">
        <Name>student2Name</Name>
    </Student>
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />
    <Lesson student="student2" teacher="teacher2"  />
    <Lesson student="student3" teacher="teacher3"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher2"  />
    <Lesson student="student3" teacher="teacher3"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />
    <Lesson student="student2" teacher="teacher4"  />
    <Lesson student="student1" teacher="teacher1"  />
</PrivateSchool>
```

**it produces the correct result**:

```
teacher1Name student1 3
```

**In your real expression you'll have `$limit` set to `10` and will only return the teachers' names**:

```
for $limit in 10,
    $t in /*/Teacher,
    $id in $t/@id,
    $s in /*/Student/@id,
    $numLessons in
        count(/*/Lesson[@teacher eq $id
                      and @student eq $s])
 return
    if($numLessons gt $limit)
      then ($t/Name, '&#xA;')
      else ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by Michael Kay for xpath 2.0 is correct, but aproximate. An exact solution for the xml posted at the question would be (without absolute paths):

```
//Teacher[
           for $t in . return 
             some $s in //Student satisfies 
               count(//Lesson[@teacher = $t/@id and @student = $s/@id]) gt 1
         ]/Name
```

(I used "gt 1" instead of "gt 10" in order to get some result)